# Why axios cause Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

I have pretty basic axios code:

```
axios.get(GEO_IP)
.then(res => res)
.catch(err => err);
```

Also, I set next axios defaults:

```
axios.defaults.headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.common.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

authorization token no needed for this public API. When I try to fire query using axios.get, I see next error in console:

> Failed to load https://ipfind.co/me?auth=8964b0f3-4da1-46eb-bcb4-07a9614a6946: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

When I rewrite axios using native XMLHttpRequest:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    // result
  }
};
http.open("GET", GEO_IP, true);
http.send();
});`
```

Everything works fine, without any errors. Could someone clarify why axios query causes the error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Same origin policy, that is what happens when you request a different domain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @epascarello — So why doesn't the problem occur with XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says:

> Response to preflight request

This has nothing to do with axios. You are trying to send *different* requests. When you are using axios, you are setting up the request in such a way that a preflight is required.

> ```
> axios.defaults.headers["content-type"] = "application/json";
> axios.defaults.headers.common.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
> ```

Either of the above would trigger a preflight.

The XMLHttpRequest version (which doesn't set HTTP headers) doesn't require a preflight, so the server not supporting the preflight isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This means that while your server sends the right CORS headers for the GET request, it isn't for the OPTIONS request that is being sent by axios as part of the preflight request.

Some requests don't require a preflight request. But I'm guessing that axios always sends one.

[See MDN for more details on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

Comment: "But I'm guessing that axios always sends one." — It doesn't.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that axios was sending a different request than the XHR request.